# Sending Data from UITextField to PHP script via NSURLConnection or JSon

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitextfield

Hi I would like to know how I can go about sending data from 4 UITextField's to a PHP script on a website using NSURLConnection or JSon. Whatever is easier, how can I do this exactly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part of it are you unsure of? Extracting the data from the text field or sending the data to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way (synchronous)

```
NSString strForTextField1 = textField1.text;
NSString strForTextField2 = textField1.text;
NSString strForTextField3 = textField1.text;
NSString strForTextField4 = textField1.text;

//Build the request
NSString *stringOfRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.yourserver.com?var1=%@&var2=%@&var3=%@&var4=%@", strForTextField1, strForTextField2, strForTextField3, strForTextField4];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringOfRequest];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
//send it synchronous
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if(!error)
{
    //log response
    NSLog(@"Response from server = %@", responseString);
}
```